# How can I fix this error?

Tags: networking, security, snort

I installed snort IDS system on windows 11 and when I tried to run this command:

```
snort -i 4 -c c:\snort\etc\snort.conf -T
```

as mentioned in a Youtube video I encountered this error:

```
ERROR: c:\snort\etc\c:\snort\rules\local.rules(0) Unable to open rules file "c:\snort\etc\c:\snort\rules\local.rules": Invalid argument.
Fatal Error, Quitting..
```

how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`c:\snort\etc\c:\snort\rules\local.rules` is not a valid path. You should open `c:\snort\etc\snort.conf` and search the offending line which contains this path.

Comment: Thanks, Frédéric